# Cannot install Cairo packages in Arch Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, r, gcc

I've install r and cairo library for Arch Linux distribution. But when I install the cairo package I've got following error.

> cairogd.c: In function ‘ptr_to_raw’:
>
> cairogd.c:491:18: error: expected expression before ‘!=’ token   if
>   (TYPEOF(ptr) != EXTPTRSXP)
>
> cairogd.c: In function ‘raw_to_ptr’:
>   cairogd.c:509:18: error: expected expression before ‘!=’ token   if
>   (TYPEOF(ptr) != EXTPTRSXP)
>
> cairogd.c:511:18: error: expected expression before ‘!=’ token
>     if (TYPEOF(raw) != RAWSXP)

I've also install all cairo requirement in Arch Linux. 
My gcc version is "gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)"

I've search and googling, and found they just install the freetype2 packages. When I try it, its cannot solve my problem.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

Bayu Permadi

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in freetype2 (see the corresponding bug report in freetype https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?45376 and Cairo https://github.com/s-u/Cairo/issues/13).

Installing `freetype2-git` from AUR will solve the problem until freetype2 is updated in the main repository.